# Create Bot with Rest API or SDK

Tags: botframework, azure-sdk-.net, azure-bot-service

I want to be able to create an Azure bot with a rest api or sdk if possible. I figured out how to create the AAD V2 app that the bot needs, but am stuck on creating the bot.

I found the following [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService/0.9.1-preview) which sounds like what I want but gives me an error. This is how I am using it.

```
var cred = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
            clientSecret,
            tenantId,
            AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

        var azure = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService.AzureBotServiceClient(cred);
        azure.SubscriptionId = "subscriptionId";

        var bot = new Bot
        {
            Location = "global",
            Properties = new BotProperties
            {
                Description = "Description of New Bot",
                DisplayName = "MyNewBotCreatedFromConsole",
                Endpoint = "https://myurl",
                Kind = "sdk",
                Sku = new Sku(SkuName.F0, SkuTier.Free),
                Location = "global",
                MsaAppId = "appId",
                MsaAppPassword = "password"
            },
        };

        var newBot = await azure.Bots.CreateWithHttpMessagesAsync("resourceGroup", "test-bot-my-1",
            bot);
```

When using fiddler I see the following response:

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidBotData","message":"Bot is not valid. Errors: BotServiceRuntimeVersion: RuntimeVersion is required. "}}
```

I'm not sure if this is a header I am supposed to pass along or some other problem? Does someone know if I am on the right path to doing what I want to do?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem, can't find any reference to RuntimeVersion, in the SDK nor anywhere in Internet. There is no such thing also in configuration scripts. What we are missing?

Comment: I wish I knew. Let me know if you discover anything.

Comment: I also have a Github issue about this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/381

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are going about this the wrong way.  Take a look at these resources:

This is a good place to start: [QuickStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-sdk-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

From there you can explore more of the docs.  You can also find samples here: [Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples)

We also have a visx template for visual studio is you wish to start that way: [Visx Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4)

For authentication you can see this walkthrough:[Add Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did successfully create a bot through Visual Studio and inside Azure. But I really want to be able to do all that programmatically. Is that possible?

Comment: the CLI tool is probably the closest thing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tools-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-3.0